# Mixing OpenMP with pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, openmp

My question is whether is it a good idea to mix OpenMP with pthreads. Are there applications out there which combine these two. Is it a good practice to mix these two? Or typical applications normally just use one of the two.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically it's better to just use one or the other. But for myself at least, I do regularly mix the two and it's safe if it's done correctly.

The most common case I do this is where I have a lower-level library that is threaded using pthreads, but I'm calling it in a user application that uses OpenMP.

There are some cases where it isn't safe. If for example, you kill a pthread before you exit all OpenMP regions in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so..

Its not a good idea. See the thing is, OpenMP is basically made for portability. Now if u are using pthread, then you are loosing the very essence of it!

pthread could only be supported by POSIX compliant OS's. While OpenMP could be used virtually on any OS provided they have a support for it.

Anyway, OpenMP gives you an abstraction much higher than what is provided by pthead.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

The purpose of OpenMP and pthreads are different. OpenMP is perfect to write a loop-level parallelism. However, OpenMP is not adequate to express sophisticated thread communications and synchronizations. OpenMP does not support all kinds of synchronizations, such as condition variables.

The caveat would be, as Mystrical pointed out, handling and accessing native threads within OpenMP parallel constructs.

FYI, Intel's TBB and Cilk Plus are also often used in a mixed way.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and Linux it seems to work just fine. However, OpenMP does not work on a Mac if it is run in a new thread. It only works in the main thread.

It appears that the behavior of how to mix the two threading modules is not defined. Some platform/compilers support it, others do not.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I do it all the time. You have to be careful. Why do it, though? Because there are some instances in which you have to! In complicated tasking models, such as pipelined functions where you want to keep the pipe going, it may be the only way to take advantage of all the power available.

Answer (score 0):

I find very hard that you would need to use pthreads if you already use OpenMP. You could use a **section** pragma to run procedures with different functions. I personally have used it to implement pipeline parallelism.

Nowadays OpenMP does much more than pthreads, so if you use OpenMP you are covered. For instance, GCC 5.0 forward implements OpenMP extensions that exports code to GPU. :D