# can we use the func in pthreads to invoke openmp directives?

Tags: performance, pthreads, openmp, mixed

Can I ask that can we get performance improved by using OpenMP in the funcs which is created by pthreads handlers?

Like:

```
     pthread_create(,funchandler,);
     void funchandler(void* pthis )
     {
       ***
       #pragma omp parallel for  
       ***
     }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing OpenMP with pthreads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433685/mixing-openmp-with-pthreads)

Comment: Having OpenMP parallel regions created by threads that are neither the main thread of the program nor an OpenMP worker thread is a non-standard use of OpenMP. It might work with certain compilers and OpenMP runtimes and fail with others. If you want your code to be portable, you shouldn't be using OpenMP in such a way.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am going to verify it by different compilers!